# GetHBITMAP утечка памяти

Tags: c++, gdi, gdi+

Почему здесь происходит утечка памяти?

```
    HBITMAP hBitmap;
    myBitmap.GetHBITMAP(0xFFF, &hBitmap);
    SendMessageW(hLogo, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
    UpdateWindow(windowHandle);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут не только утечка, но и освобождение ресурса, который используется. Потому что `STM_SETIMAGE` не копирует переданный битмап, и возвращает дескриптор предыдущего битмапа. Клиент обязан следить, чтобы установленный битмап оставался валидным, и отвечает за уничтожение ранее установленного битмапа после его замены.

Comment: спасибо исправил